# "OuterSubscriber is not defined" when bundeling with rollup.js

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5, rollupjs

After updating to Angular2 RC7 I get the folloing JavaScript error when running in the browser:

> OuterSubscriber is not defined

This only happens when I create a bundle using `rollup.js`. If I run the application with the JavaScript not bundled it works fine.

The error must somehow be related with `rxjs` since `OuterSubscriber` is part of it. I checked the bundle and could not find `OuterSubscriber` there. I suppose `rollup.js` thinks that it is not necessary and therefore does not include it.

Environment:

- `angular, v2.0.0-rc.7`
- `rxjs, v5.0.0-beta.12`
- `systemjs, v0.19.27`
- `gulp-rollup, v2.4.0`
- `rollup-stream, v1.13.0`

In the `system.js` config I map the `umd` modules (e.g. `core.umd.js`) for `angular`. For `rxjs` I use a classical mapping as in this [example](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/29f3dcda1a06b955d83fccb2a94586eb).

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I am running angular2 RC6 and rxjs 5 beta 11, have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollup 0.34.0 works with 2.0.0-rc.7 and verified Rollup 0.34.0 works with 2.0.0 also but I was able to replicate the issue with 0.35.0

Comment: That fixed it. I just had to make sure that non of the other npm packages requires rolloup bigger than 0.34.x and then it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems with `rollup` currently.

- `rollup` doesn't normalize slashes in paths (`'/'` vs `'\\'`) and that [issue is still open](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/895). To fix it `rollup.config.js` needs the following addition:

```
resolveId(id, from){
    if (id.startsWith('rxjs/') || id.startsWith('rxjs\\')){
        let result = `${__dirname}/node_modules/rxjs-es/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
        return result.replace(/\//g, "\\"); // Add this
    }
}
```

- It breaks ES2015 code, but ES5 works fine, so it needs compiling `rxjs-es` to ES5 with ES2015 modules and making rollup resolver use it instead. Here is a separate `tsconfig.rx.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "ES2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "temp/rxjs",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "node_modules/rxjs-es/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules/rxjs-es/rx.js"
    ]
}
```

and `rollup.config.js`:

```
resolveId(id, from){
    if (id.startsWith('rxjs/') || id.startsWith('rxjs\\')){
        let result = `${__dirname}/temp/rxjs/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
        //let result = `${__dirname}/node_modules/rxjs-es/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
        return result.replace(/\//g, "\\");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've verified OuterSubscriber is missing from my bundle

Comment: I've verified OuterSubscriber is missing from my bundle but I'm operating from OS X and the above solution is for Windows machines

Comment: Second part may actually fix your problem